# Group by / distinct combined with sum?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a sql statement like this:

```
select a.id, a.valfrom ...
  inner join ...
  where ...;
```

As a result I have this:

```
id    val
---------
 3     10
 3     10
 3     10
 9     21
 9     21
11      2
11      2
13     30
```

So you can see, one id has one value.

If I do a group by (a.id), I get:

```
id    val
---------
 3     10
 9     21
11      2
13     30
```

What I want to get of the last result is the sum:
10+21+2+30 = 63.

So how can I get the sum as a single result?
If I do a sum(a.val) and use group by (a.id) I do not get 63, I get the sum for every id, for example id=3 -> 10+10+10 = 30.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't want a GROUP BY, then.  You also can't select the ID correctly in standard SQL.  You just want:

`SELECT SUM(val) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, val FROM ...) AS foo`

But, MySQL supports a few extensions to standard SQL syntax which MIGHT make this work:

`SELECT DISTINCT id, SUM(val) FROM ...`

Comment: Select from select equals "boooooo".

Grouping by is the way, but with something they all have in common: the `NULL`. See my answer

Comment: I did this and I get the error message:
"Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: I solved it. I have to use AS for the subselected table and AS for "id" and "val" in the subselect

Comment: makes sense.  can't SUM a column that isn't a number yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you query is

```
select a.id, a.valfrom ...
  inner join ...
  where ...;
```

try this:

```
select sum(distinct a.valfrom)
  inner join ...
  where ...;
```

No "group by", hands down.

Answer (score 1):

Using a subselect and distinct:

```
  select sum(valform) from (
    select distinct a.id, a.valfrom ...
    inner join ...
    where ...
  )
```

Or using group-by:

```
  select sum(valform) from (
    select a.id, min(a.valfrom)
    inner join ...
    where ...
    group by a.id
  )
```

But I reckon the first query will be faster.

Comment: technically, in standard SQL you must GROUP on all columns which are not aggregates, if memory serves correctly...  MySQL doesn't enforce the restriction for some reason, though.

Comment: without group by, I get the result as you can see in my first post. That is not the result I want to have.

Comment: @Borealid: You are correct - [MySQL documented the "feature"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html);  IIRC, SQLite has the same GROUP BY functionality as MySQL (grrrr...)...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the Distinct on which you have to do the summation.

```
select ID,Sum(Distinct Val) 
from Table
Group By ID;
```

Comment: What if two different ids have the same value though, you would run a distinct on Val and lose one of them for the SUM.

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick :)

```
select a.id, a.valfrom, SUM(val) as mySum ...
  inner join ...
  where ...
GROUP BY NULL
```

Comment: What if two different IDs have the same value?

Comment: This results in the same thing as Borealid's DISTINCT example, but it's less clear.